# MySQL database field is varchar when it should be datetime

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have taken over a website and the original developer stored dates as varchar in the database rather than datetime. Date fields such as Date of Birth have a variety of formats e.g. dd/mm/yyyy, mm/dd/yyyy, mmddyyyy etc.

I would like to migrate this field to the proper data type, but there are hundreds of rows. What is the best approach for migrating the field? The php code will most likely also need to be updated.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Some date will be impossible to reconcile programatically.  For example, is `03/04/2000` the 3rd of April, or the 4th of March?  Both are completely legitimate.  Your best bet may be to add a new column, with the proper data-type, and ask the users to re-enter their date-of-birth.

Comment: I am just wondering how a field would have multiple formats? Storing a date in VARCHAR is fine to some extent. But in different formats, that too messing with dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy is disastrous. Is there any way to identify the first two characters as month or date? If there is a PHP code that uses this field it may have that. You can use that, to first, convert all of these to a single format, say, dd/mm/yyyy. Then you can create a new date column and delete this column. Of course, the PHP code that uses these tables may need a change based how it uses the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best approach for migrating the field?

Possible way:

Step 1. Add generated column which converts string-valued dates to DATE datatype:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
  ADD COLUMN dSomeDate DATE AS (STR_TO_DATE(SomeDate, {converting pattern})) STORED;
```

Step 2. Find all queries which selects from old column (including ones in functions, procedures, triggers, events, ...), rewrite them to new column usage and apply.

Step 3. Find all modifying queries and mark them, rewrite them to new column usage, but not apply.

Step 4. Stop the system. Make complete backup and ensure that it is consistent.

Step 5. Alter table, remove generated column but add regular one. Fill it with converted value with according UPDATE. Remove old column.

Step 6. Apply all rewrited data modifying code.

Step 7. Start the system and ensure that everything works without problems.

Repeat this procedure for each column to be altered. Of course, you may apply this method to a lot of columns (or to all of them) at the same time, but this increases the probability of the problem due to something was not taken into account.